# jquery how to append as first child?

Tags: jquery, append

i have a span like this one:

```
<span id="tablinks" class="links">
<a href="#" class="back" title="">go</a>
</span>
```

And i like to append as first child a new link:

```
<span id="tablinks" class="links">
<a href="#" class="new" title="">new</a>
<a href="#" class="back" title="">go</a>
</span>
```

i try to append it

```
$("#tablinks").append("<a class=\"new\" href=\"#\">new</a>");
```

but this results in:

```
<span id="tablinks" class="links">
<a href="#" class="back" title="">go</a>
<a href="#" class="new" title="">new</a>
</span>
```

i tried before it

```
$("#tablinks").before("<a class=\"new\" href=\"#\">new</a>");
```

but the result was:

```
<a href="#" class="new" title="">new</a>
<span id="tablinks" class="links">
<a href="#" class="back" title="">go</a>
</span>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Use [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend) instead of `append()`. `before()` would work too, but you need to select the existing `a` element, not the `#tablinks` element.

Comment: $("#tablinks").prepend("<a class=\"new\" href=\"#\">new</a>");